# CSS opacity performance. Image fading

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I'm trying to fade in-out my image for my photo gallery switching. All it's done in JavaScript which simply changes the opacity CSS value of the image element. This is really laggy (slow) on some computers - for example my laptop which isn't extremely powerful, but it's brand new (Asus Eeepc).

I was wondering if there's anyway I can fix this performance issue. I've seen demos of Canvas animation and HTML5 applied to images and they're really smooth on my laptop. I wonder if I can apply the same thing to my image fading feature.

Any ideas? How would I do this?

Comment: Surprised it's laggy - how fast you changing the opacity? I achieved a smooth transition doing something very similar updating every 100 ms.

Comment: Be wary of HTML5 at the moment, it's going to be a while longer before it's widely supported by the browsers actually in use (although the latest versions of most browsers support it, most of the internet doesn't use the latest version).

Comment: Can you provide your code? That will make it easier to figure out the performance issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I quickly threw together an example of an image fading away using the `canvas` tag as requested: http://jsfiddle.net/6wmrd/12/ (Only tested in Chrome and Firefox)

I´m not sure if there is any performance gain though, but here is at least a very simple example of how it can be done. It should also be noted that this was done in 5 min so the code can be improved and optimized.

Otherwise, from my experience, if you have a solid background behind the image, I have found that it is sometimes smoother to fade an element over the image with the same color as the background.

Other ways you can improve performance could be to reduce FPS. If I´m not mistaken MooTools has 50 FPS as standard. However, reducing the FPS might influence the perceived performance.

Answer (score 2):

Here is code that works for all browsers:
add to head :

```
/*  ****************************
    * updated for all browsers by 
    * Evan Neumann of Orbiting Eden on 
    * October 6, 2011.      
    * www.orbitingeden.com - evan@orbitingeden.com
    * original version only worked for IE
    *****************************/
<!-- Begin
    /*  *****************************
     *  * editable by user
     *  ***************************/
    var slideShowSpeed      = 5000; // Set slideShowSpeed (milliseconds)        shared by IE and other borwsers
    var crossFadeDuration   = 5;    // Duration of crossfade (1/10 second)      shared by IE and other borwsers
    var crossFadeIncrement  = .05;  //crossfade step amount (1 is opaque)   for non-IE browsers

    // Specify the image files
var Pic = new Array();      // do not change this line
// to add more images, just continue the pattern, adding to the array below
Pic[0] = 'images/dare2wear-427ED-e.jpg';        
Pic[1] = 'images/PBW_3238EDSM-e.jpg';           
Pic[2] = 'images/dare2wear-441_2ED-e.jpg';      

/*  ********************************
    * do not change anything below this line
    **********************************/
var f = 0;          //index of the foreground picture
var b = 1;          //index of the background picture
var p = Pic.length; //number of pictures loaded and in queue - this may increase as time goes on depending on number and size of pictures and network speed

//load the picture url's into an image object array
//used to control download of images and for IE shortcut
var preLoad = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < p; i++) { 
    preLoad[i] = new Image();
    preLoad[i].src = Pic[i];
}

function runSlideShow() {//this is trigerred by <body onload="runSlideShow()" > 
    //if IE, use alternate method
    if (document.all) {
        document.images.SlideShow.style.filter="blendTrans(duration=2)";
        document.images.SlideShow.style.filter="blendTrans(duration=crossFadeDuration)";
        document.images.SlideShow.filters.blendTrans.Apply();
    }

    //increment the foreground image source
    document.images.SlideShow.src = preLoad[f].src;

    //if IE, use the shortcut
    if(document.all) {
        document.images.SlideShow.filters.blendTrans.Play();
    }
    //all other browser use opacity cycling
    else    {
        var imageContainer  = document.getElementById('imageContainer');
        var image           = document.images.SlideShow;
        //convert an integer to a textual number for stylesheets
        imageContainer.style.background = "url('"+Pic[b]+"')";
        //set opacity to fully opaque (not transparent)
        image.style.opacity = 1;
        //run fade out function to expose background image
        fadeOut();
    }

    //increment picture index
    f++;
    //if you have reached the last picture, start agin at 0
    if (f > (p - 1)) f = 0;
    //set the background image index (b) to one advanced from foreground image
    b = f+1;
    //if b is greater than the number of pictures, reset to zero
    if(b >= p)  {b = 0;}

    //recursively call this function again ad infinitum
    setTimeout('runSlideShow()', slideShowSpeed);
}

function fadeOut(){
    //convert to element
    var el = document.images.SlideShow;

    //decrement opacity by 1/20th or 5%
    el.style.opacity = el.style.opacity - crossFadeIncrement;
    //if we have gone below 5%, escape out to the next picture
    if(el.style.opacity <= crossFadeIncrement)  {
        return; 
    }
    //wait 50 milliseconds then continue on to decrement another 5%
    setTimeout('fadeOut()', crossFadeDuration*10);
}
//  End -->
```

and add two elements to the body. The first is a container background element. I have used a div, but td, body and others should work too. The second is the foreground image. Lastly, within the `<body>` tag, add the onload function call

```
  <body onLoad="runSlideShow()">
      <!-- this is the main image background -->
      <div id="imageContainer">
        <!-- this is the main image foreground -->
        <img id="SlideShow" name='SlideShow' width="324" height="486">
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Luca one way to make it faster is to use hardware acceleration and webkit transforms.  The problem is that different browser support this to different degrees.  See

http://mir.aculo.us/2010/06/04/making-an-ipad-html5-app-making-it-really-fast/

hopefully in the not-to-distant futures support for hardware acceleration in the browser will be better.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the front page of this [site](http://www.su3analytics.com) It's 5 images that fade in and out in rotation, pure css2, html4, javascript, and is cross-browser (as far as I am aware). The javascript is a bit hackneyed - written some time ago :) but it seems to be smooth enough. See how it is on your machine. If it lags, you could try with a slower update, say 150 or 200ms instead of a 100.