# CSS performance: is it okay to make significant use of an overlaid pattern on coloured elements?

Tags: css, background-image

I'm about to build a design which involves quite a lot of textured backgrounds which use the same parchment pattern but in different colours. Obviously I could create and export a different tiled background image for each colour, but I'm wondering whether it might be cleverer to create a single monochrome pattern which I can overlay elements which have the necessary block background colour.

My question is whether this approach would be okay from a performance point of view. I've done this before for small elements, but I'm wondering whether it would be unacceptably slow to use this technique across many elements, for example the site's background, several divs on a given page, buttons etc. Experience tells me that older browsers choke a bit on too much png alpha (although this project is IE8+, mercifully).

Any thoughts?

EDIT: when I talk of performance my main concern isn't download time but actual page rendering performance. I've noticed alpha PNGs lagging some browsers in the past, so extensive use of even a small tiled texture might (I surmise) cause similar problems.

Download performance isn't an issue at this stage.

Comment: I'd go with the single png. Bear in mind though, even on ie8, if you do any animating, you may get jaggies while fading in and out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance of what? If performance of loading, then using fewer files will speed things up. If performance of scrolling, that will depend on how you build it and your target audience.

I built a site years ago which had a US audience and used a monochromatic transparent PNG which overlaid a solid color. I tested this on quite a few machines. The only display performance issues were if something was scrolling over the top of something else that wasn't. For example, if you have two patterns overlaid and one scrolls but the other does, you're going to see some redraw issues on slower machines and mobile devices.

This was only for a handful of elements, including the page background. If you're applying it on dozens of elements per page, that might start showing issues on older machines. But it will still be less resource intensive than, for example, a large JS slider with transitions.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advice to go with the single monochrome pattern. I suggest this because, in this case the browser loads only one image file vs loading multiple files in the other alternative. If your site is small and doesnt get much traffic it probably will not matter much, however it is always a good practice to optimize the amount of work you do.

Comment: Sorry my reference to performance was about rendering speed, not page download speed -- I should have made that clearer in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

From a performance point of view, I would say stick with the same parchment pattern in different colors. I agree that your solution is cleaner - that's what I'd prefer - but you're only going to alienate users who possibly receive decreased performance on the client end (users with low-end tech? mobile devices?), whereas the extra bandwidth you would otherwise save using the monochrome pattern is (IMO) less likely to alienate users based on bandwidth (how big a difference are we talking?). I can't find any actual benchmarks for these situations.

Here are some links that discuss some related aspects of this. Note the first link has a user saying there are memory leaks in PNG alpha 24-bit in IE8.

[Which is superior, CSS transparency or PNG Transparency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549768/which-is-superior-css-transparency-or-png-transparency)

[CSS opacity performance. Image fading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761423/css-opacity-performance-image-fading)

Comment: There's also the delightful thought of applying a simple class in LESS (.parchment) to any element and I know it'll immediately take on the correct look without having to faff around with images. Hm..

Comment: Thanks for the links, and the memory leak issue is interesting. I'll experiment -- my plan was to use something like 100x100 (the larger the tile the faster it is to render, apparently) and an 8bit PNG, so that might be outside the memory leak bug. Worst case scenario I can create a set of coloured textures for those browsers, or feed them no textures at all. The elegance of using a single texture on multiple elements seems too good to pass up :)